# Windows 10 broken after running newsid

Tags: windows-10, sysprep, sid

I know newsid was retired by its creator Russinovik almost 10 year ago and so it is definitely a bad idea to run in on windows 10 machine. Anyway I received two new computers which probably were generated from the same image and they had identical **machine sid**. I had nothing to lose so I decided to try.

Now the Windows 10 tries to boot but it stops because it says it is broken.
I tried to start in all of the available **recovery mode** but it fails too. I can only get a command prompt.

Is there something I can do before reinstalling Windows 10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you shouldn't have used the tool. Windows has similar functionality builtin. As the computers are new, I assume you don't have much to lose (no actual data saved, yet).

1. Go to the original stage by cloning the hard drive from the working installation.
2. Start the computer and run Sysprep

   ```
   sysprep /generalize /shutdown /oobe
   ```
3. Computer will shut down and on the next boot it'll start *the Out Of Box Experience* (OOBE) wizard.

The Sysprep works best when done before taking the image for cloning. It wouldn't hurt trying this on the recovery command prompt, but I'm not sure if it helps. Let us know.